Citing with biblatex is not working
I have been trying to cite some papers in my document for hours now and it is not working (meaning they show up incorrectly in the text and they are not linked). What am I doing wrong? I use the following code:
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
  urlcolor=black}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum,pdflscape}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag} 
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow} 
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, patterns}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
%\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % Top strut- space within table
\newcommand\B{\rule[-2.6ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut - space within table


\title{\vspace{-2.7cm} Blah }

\author{Blah }


\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\cite{goldin2022}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


What does the .blg file say?

Please reduce your example to the code needed to reproduce the error. Then try to use biblatex-examples.bib instead of (unknown by everyone but you) References.bib. → https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407

BTW: TeX.SX uses UTF8 encoding for the code (as most LaTeX editors also do). So \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} should not be used for example code here. And you should avoid loading package more than once. It's not an error, but complicates changes of the document.

A document like this needs to be compiled with LaTeX (where "LaTeX" means pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX - given you load inputenc with latin1 that's most likely pdfLaTeX), then Biber and then twice more with LaTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can make your editor run Biber for you. If you did run Biber you should have a .blg file in your document folder. Open it (despite what your system may tell you, it is a simple text file) and post its full contents here.

Follow the MWE  of here setp by step, and it should work. Then modify the MWE to repeat the renderization  but with your References.bib and some of your cites, and still should work. Otherwise, probably you have some mistakes in your references. In special, check that you have not active characters as %  or & in some field without the backslash before .Read the error messages also could help.
